# Questions and Answers Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm Trying to achieve, pretty much the same behavior, as the Questions from StackOverflow.

`User creates a Question` **-** `other Users can Answer`

I started by creating a **`Questions Scaffold`** with the appropriate relations:

- user.rb -> **has_many :questions**
- question.rb -> **belongs_to :user**

Now for the **Answer** Part, do i have to *Create a new Scaffold* ? And how can i link the Answer with the specific Question?

As i'm fairly new to Rails and just getting things work, help would much be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**create answer resource:**

```
rails g resource Answer question_id:integer content:text user_id:integer
```

**answer.rb**

```
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :user
```

**question.rb**

```
has_many :answers
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :answers
```

**the above relations will allow you to make calls like:**

```
user.questions
question.answers
user.answers
```

etc..

**in questions/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @question.id %> - <%= @question.content %>

<%= form_for @question.answer.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Magnum, it seems that today your my man :) Small Error -> http://pastebin.com/F9SNzZrV . I'm Getting a **undefined method `answer' for** error.

Comment: enter this chat:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37844/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18950256-questions-and-answers-controller

Comment: Thansk a Lot :) You're Awesome !!